# How to reconfigure VCS of IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Hi I am using Intellij IDEA 14 (Mac), I opened a project.
I went to menu VCS and I enable the version control and I selected Git. But actually later I realized that I should have selected Subversion.

Now how can I reconfigure it to be Subversion instead?

[image]
The above screenshot is taken by go "File"->"Other Settings"->"Default Settings"

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings dialog ("File > Settings > Version Control") and for the directory that's being managed by git choose Subversion instead of Git.

[image]

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 14 doesn't have the menu you said.

Comment: Don't you have "Version Control" menu at all (see edited answer and screenshot) ?

Comment: See my screenshot above . seems I don't have any place for me to change. which version of IDEA are you using?

Comment: I see. It seems you don't have a project, you've opened default settings from IDEA splash screen? In order the "Add" button to be enabled, you must have an opened project.

Comment: I think so. How to let it not use default settings?

Comment: This seems to be a bug of IDEA - allowing you to choose a Version Control from the startup screen but NOT allowing you to change it. Just create or import a project and go to the same screen - the Add/Remove buttons will be enabled.